# How to get rid of the extra legend entry of Pandas plot()?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe:

```
>>> drawdata
                   sales       mg
ID     RPT_Date                  
600809 20120331  22.1401  13.5591
       20120630  38.1565  22.8968
       20120930  52.5098  31.5909
```

And below command draws a bar plot as below img:

```
>>> drawdata.unstack('ID').plot(kind='bar', use_index=True)
<matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot object at 0x035A9D70>
```

[image]

And my question is shown as the annotation: how to get rid of the extra legend entry ?

(this url is related: 
[How to barplot Pandas dataframe columns aligning by sub-index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492530/how-to-barplot-pandas-dataframe-columns-aligning-by-sub-index) )

**EDIT: (More information for HYRY method)**

---

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import itertools
import pandas as pd
import io

text = '''\
ID RPT_Date sales mg
000568 20120331 22.140 13.559
000568 20120630 38.156 22.896
000568 20120930 52.509 31.590
'''

drawdata = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(text), delimiter = ' ', converters = {0:str})
drawdata.set_index(['ID','RPT_Date'], inplace = True)

ax  = drawdata.unstack('ID').plot(kind='bar', use_index=True, legend=False)

display_acct_list = list(drawdata.columns)
legend_list = list(itertools.product(display_acct_list, list(set(drawdata.index.get_level_values('ID')))))
legend_list = [x[0] + '-' + x[1] for x in legend_list]

ax.legend(legend_list, loc='best', fancybox=True, shadow=True)

ax.set_xlabel("")
```

The chart is missing the "color box" in legend .

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn off the legend title by:

```
drawdata.unstack('ID').plot().get_legend().set_title("")
```

Or you can draw the legend by yourself:

```
import pylab as pl
drawdata.unstack('ID').plot(legend=False)
pl.legend(loc="best")
```

For your second question:

That is because there is a dash line in the plot, if you zoom out a little , you will see it. When you set legend labels, the first label will give to the dash line. You can fix it by following line:

```
ax.legend(ax.containers, legend_list, loc='best', fancybox=True, shadow=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. It works. But as I need to customize the legend text and assign the axes object to a variable for later on processing,  so I use the second method. Now I meet another issue: the first "color box" inside the legend is missing! I attach the whole code and the chart in the update region. Would you please take a look ?

Comment: Ok, fixed it, please check the answer again.

Comment: Great! Solve one of my biggest headache. Thanks very much.